# CSS in browser - "inspect element" section does not change css rules applied

Tags: css, browser, element, inspect

I have three pages layout, each page has a same header section but a different  content under the header. Each page has a separate css file which I can see in the browser as well. Also all pages have the same normalize file applied.

Although I got for all three pages the same css rules for their header in each css file one page does not have applied those rules and I can see it in the inspect element section in the browser that that page has different css rules applied - from normalize file. I have already cleaned cache of the chrome browser but the mistake still appears.

Can somebody advise please?

Thank you.

Comment: Ensure the normalise file is included first, followed by your content CSS file. Whatever comes last overrides any conflicting styles. It would be worth you reading up on CSS specificity if you are not already familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have added css file reference in good order?

Comment: Yes, I did checked that before too. All three pages have css files - normalize on the top, then main, then responsive.